# SQL Select Statement Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three SQL Tables (Movies, MovieCopy and RentalTransactions). Movies holds data about Movies, MovieCopy holds data in relation to the number of copies of a particular DVD etc and is used as an associative entity between Movies and RentalTransactions, RentalTransactions holds data about Movie Rentals.

Movies has 10 rows of data (Movie1, Movie2, Movie 3 etc up to 10). MovieCopy has 30 rows, these 30 rows are made up of 3 copies of each of the 10 films in the Movies table. RentalTransactions has 10 rows, which relate to the first 10 rows in MovieCopy.

I am trying to run a report which will show me all the movies of type 'DVD' which are currently not out on loan, so this would be the 20 remaining copies of films in the MovieCopy table.

Below is my SQL code for trying to pull this report but when I execute this SQL i am returned 290 rows, I'm not sure why this is exactly happening, ideally I would like to see only the 20 rows in MovieCopy which are not in RentalTransactions.

```
Select Movies.Movie_Name, Movies.Movie_Type, 
    Movies.Movie_Medium, Count(MovieCopy.Movie_CopyID) as Copies 
FROM Movies,MovieCopy,RentalTransactions 
WHERE Movies.Movie_Medium = 'DVD' and Movies.MovieID = MovieCopy.MovieID 
    and MovieCopy.Movie_CopyID <> RentalTransactions.Movie_CopyID;
```

Can anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Movies.Movie_Name, Movies.Movie_Type, 
    Movies.Movie_Medium, Count(MovieCopy.Movie_CopyID) as Copies 
FROM Movies,MovieCopy,RentalTransactions 
WHERE Movies.Movie_Medium = 'DVD' and Movies.MovieID = MovieCopy.MovieID 
    and MovieCopy.Movie_CopyID NOT IN (SELECT Movie_CopyID FROM RentalTransactions );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to remove all rows from `MovieCopy` where a `RentalTransactions` exist, and `GROUP BY` to get the counters per movie.

```
Select
  Movies.Movie_Name, Movies.Movie_Type, Movies.Movie_Medium,
  Count(1) as Copies 
FROM Movies
JOIN MovieCopy ON ( MovieCopy.MovieId = Movies.MovieId )
WHERE Movies.Movie_Medium = 'DVD'
NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM RentalTransactions
  WHERE RentalTransactions.Movie_CopyID = MovieCopy.Movie_CopyID
)
GROUP BY
  Movies.Movie_Name, Movies.Movie_Type, Movies.Movie_Medium
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is wrong. You are using the presence of an entry in RentalTransactions as a flag for the copy being rented or not. However, when you do your query this does not work as you expect. The query will find all cases where a movie is of type 'DVD' and has a corresponding entry in MovieCopy but for each transaction that is not itself. This will create duplicates.

Also, this will force you to delete entries every time someone returns the movie copy which will destroy any form of history.

What you need to have is create a new attribute in MovieCopy and set it to true/false depending on if the copy was rented or not.

Comment: How would I go about setting it to true/false depending on whether it was rented or not?

I'm guessing the only way of knowing if it was even rented was if a MovieCopy_ID exists in RentalTransactions?

Comment: When the event occurs you can just use an UPDATE query to modify the flag of the proper MovieCopy and set it to true/false. You will need to ALTER the table to add the new column. As I said, technically what you are doing *can* work but it has major drawbacks. Notably, you will have to delete the previous rental in order to rent again that copy of the movie. This makes it impossible to keep an history. You would have to first create a copy of the data in a separate "TransactionHistory" table and then delete the data in the former table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat complicated query.  Your version seems to have three flaws.  The first is inconsistent use of table names, such as `Transactions` in the `from` clause and `RentalTransactions` as an alias.  The second is the use of old-style joins.  The third is inconsistent use of the `group by`.

Because one way to formulate the query is using a `left outer join`, the old-style implicit joins are a real problem.

The logic is to filter the movies based on the medium.  Then, left outer join to the rental table and choose only copies with no rental record.

```
Select m.Movie_Name, m.Movie_Type, 
       m.Movie_Medium, Count(MovieCopy.Movie_CopyID) as Copies 
FROM Movies m join
     MovieCopyRental mcr
     on m.MovieID = mc.MovieID and m.Movie_Medium = 'DVD' left outer join
     RentalTransactions rt
     on mcr.Movie_CopyID = rt.Movie_CopyID and        
WHERE rt.Movie_CopyId is NULL
GROUP BY m.Movie_Name, m.Movie_Type, m.Movie_Medium;
```

If you want a list of all movies, including those with no copies, then change the `where` clause to conditional aggregation:

```
Select m.Movie_Name, m.Movie_Type, m.Movie_Medium,
       count(*) as TotalCopies, sum(rt.Movie_CopyId is NULL) as RemainingCopies 
FROM Movies m join
     MovieCopyRental mcr
     on m.MovieID = mc.MovieID and m.Movie_Medium = 'DVD' left outer join
     RentalTransactions rt
     on mcr.Movie_CopyID = rt.Movie_CopyID and        
GROUP BY m.Movie_Name, m.Movie_Type, m.Movie_Medium;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
select mov.movie_id , mov.movietitle , cpm.movie_id , cpm.movietitle from tbl_movies as mov
left join tbl_moviescopy as cpm on cpm.movie_id = mov.movie_id
where movie_type = 'DVD'
and movie_id not exists (select movie_id from rentaltransactions)
```

im sorry , created my own field names based on your question.
but hope it helps you, this would generate 4 rows , 2 from the movie table and 2 from the movie copy table